# read value from textbox inside html table cell using current row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm append data to table using for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                date = data[i].inv_Date;
                invDate = date.substring(0, 10);
                billNo = data[i].Bill_No;
                netAmt = parseFloat(data[i].Net_Amt).toFixed(2);
                paidAmt = parseFloat(data[i].Paid_Amt).toFixed(2);
                balance = (parseFloat(netAmt) - parseFloat(paidAmt)).toFixed(2); //id = "damt['+i+']"
                $("#invoiceDetailTbl tbody").append("<tr id=" + i + ">" + "<td>" + invDate + "</td>" + "<td>" + billNo + "</td>" + "<td>" + netAmt + "</td>" + "<td>" + paidAmt + "</td>" + "<td>" + '<input type="text" class="discountAmt form-control input-sm" style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Discount Amt" id="damt" name="damt' + i + '">' + "</td>" + "<td>" + '<input type="text" class="payingAmt form-control input-sm" style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Paying Amt" id="pamt">' + "</td>" + "<td>" + balance + "</td>" + "<td>" + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                totalAmt = totalAmt + parseFloat(netAmt);
                totalBalance = totalBalance + parseFloat(balance);
            }
```

i'm read value of textbox using

```
var PayingAmtValue = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.discountAmt').val();
```

but always get null value.
i'll also try this using

```
var table = document.getElementById('invoiceDetailTbl');
        var DiscountAmtValue = $(this).val();
        var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        PayingAmtValue = $(table.rows.item(rowId + 1).cells[5]).find('input').val();
```

but browser return
**uncaught TypeError :cannot read property 'cells' of null**

Comment: What about creating fiddle demo?

Comment: `var PayingAmtValue = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.discountAmt').text();`

Comment: also try using .text() but same happen, the value i need to read is in side a textbox in html cell..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `discountAmt` applied to `input` and not to `td`. You have to find `input` which is having `class="discountAmt"` inside `td`.

```
// this will find children 'td' having class="discountAmt"
var PayingAmtValue = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.discountAmt').val();
```

change above code to

```
// this will find input with 'class="discountAmt"'
var PayingAmtValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.discountAmt').val();
```